# Server can't find resources

Tags: eclipse, jersey, jax-rs, java-ee-7

After I'd tried to find the answer in the Internet, I went here to ask for your help. The problem is that server can't find the resources and gives 404 error, when I'm typing http://localhost:8081/advanced-jaxrs-01/webapi/test. Although typing http://localhost:8081/advanced-jaxrs-01 prints "Hello world". Using Tomcat 9. What's wrong with that?

pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
 instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>org.gson</groupId>
 <artifactId>advanced-jaxrs-01</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>

 <name>advanced-jaxrs-01 Maven Webapp</name>
 <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
 <url>http://www.example.com</url>

 <properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-moxy -->
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
     <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
     <version>2.16</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles/jaxrs-ri -->
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
     <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
     <version>2.16</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <finalName>advanced-jaxrs-01</finalName>
  <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to 
  parent pom) -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default- 
      bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

MyApp class

```
package org.gson;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@ApplicationPath("webapi")
public class MyApp extends Application {}
```

MyResource class

```
package org.gson;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("test")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String test() {
        return "Grace";
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your server console output on startup? And you should really use a package name of your own.

Comment: Console tells nothing. I mean no warnings

Comment: What's in your `web.xml`? Something has to trigger Jersey to actually read those annotations, after all.

Comment: here is it:                                                                                                   `<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
`

Comment: You need to tell Jersey which packages are yours, another reason to use package names of your own. See https://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey2-hello-world-example/

Comment: As I understood I have to add the following: `<servlet><servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name><servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class><init-param><param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name><param-value>com.howtodoinjava.jersey</param-value></init-param><load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup></servlet>  ` But thats not really helps(( I'm given with classNotFoundException

Comment: And the `servlet-mapping`?

Comment: I'm watching the courses on "Java brain" youtube chanel called "advanced jax-rs"(this is the video url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAG8I57epgQ&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTY40IcG584ynNqibMc1heIa&index=4) and I'm trying to create jax-rs application using just Java and without configuring web.xml(I mean writing servlet mapping in it). You may see how do I do such stuff  above

Comment: You've run the `mvn clean install` to make sure the referenced dependencies are present?

Comment: I've done mvn clean, but errors still appear

Comment: Are there any messages in your Problems View? Compile errors? How are you launching the Tomcat server?

Comment: Well, there are no errors raise up in console, when I do such job. As I'd wrote before, I'm trying to make jax-rs application using just Java with no web.xml org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer and mapping. And I get 404. This is the tutorial I'm watching now https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAG8I57epgQ&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTY40IcG584ynNqibMc1heIa&index=4 . I'm doing the same stuff as there, but I face an error. I don't know completely what to do(((

Comment: And when I tried to change org.glassfish.jersey.media and org.glassfish.jersey.bundles version up to 3.0.0-M6(last one) it says: - Missing artifact jakarta.json:jakarta.json-
  api:jar:2.0.0-RC3
 - Missing artifact org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-
  locator:jar:3.0.0-M2
 - Missing artifact org.glassfish:jakarta.json:jar:2.0.0-
  RC3

Comment: When you said the Console view had no warnings, what did it have?

Comment: There was just info about server startup and such information